# Excel Advanced Filter Criteria for Any Type of Character (numeric or text)

Tags: excel, filter, wildcard, autofilter, advanced-filter

I have in my Data Range column values as numbers or letters (1, 2...., B,C..).

Using the wildcard `"*"`for the criterion on this column only retrieves rows in which the value is a letter (B,C..).

When adding criterion `">=0"`it retrieves all data (1, 2...., B,C..).

[image]

But it is not practical as I would need to duplicate all other criteria on all the new row when I filter something.

[image]

I also get all values also by adding a blank lines to the criteria range :
[image]

But it does not work for filtering (non "*" values)

How to retrieve any type of characters?

Answer (score 0):

Criteria `<>0` fetches numeric AND text values successfully.